# Alignment Issue due to scroll bar

Tags: html, scroll

In the following code, the tool tip appears when we move our cursor to the link, tool tip is an image, the length of image can be very long. The problem is whenever length of image is long, scroll bar appears on the right side and then alignment gets disturbed. all the contents moves to left a little bit. How can I avoid that, Any help id highly appreciated. Thanks

```
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="#">Summarization Search Engine</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>You Searched for <b><i>../html/Sample Results.html</b></i></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="brand" id="0" rel="popover" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_management">It Infrastructure</a><br><p>These resources may include tangible investments like computer hardware, software, data, networks and data centre facilities, as well as the staff who are hired to maintain them.</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the associated CSS code. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @JensNeubauer Thanks for the suggestion, let me try making the fiddle.